# How to receive a webhook in asp classic?

Tags: webhooks

Im totally new to webhooks but I think I understand how it basically should work. But I need some help to really understand it and to see if I am totally wrong :-)

And I wonder how to receive a webhook? If I´m missing something, or can I just do a request.form("something") to receive it?

This is what I have now.
Im sending a json formated post with XmlHttp from `sendorder.asp` to a payment service and in it I declare a web hook in the formated json like this along with other order details.

```
webhooks"": [{" &_
      """eventName"": ""payment.checkout.completed"","&_
      """url"": ""https://mydomain.se/getorderinfo.asp"","&_
      """authorization"": ""xxxxxxxx"""
```

And in the payment service docs it say "`Easy will send the event as a HTTP POST request to the URL specified by the merchant.`"

So I guess that in my `getorderinfo.asp` page I just have a `theinfo=request.form("something")` to be able to receive the information?

But then their docs says that `"When you subscribe to a webhook, Easy will try to send the request to the specified URL until the server responds with a 200 OK status code."`

Does this mean that I have to send something back, or is the `200 OK` sent as a response to them automatically?

The json data that I´m suppose to get back looks like this.

```
{
    "id" : "f3d5043af4094d6887ee95bf16073958",
    "merchantId" : "e718004345cc48cba095a235de85c359",
    "timestamp" : "2018-01-12T09:40:19.8919+00:00",
    "event" : "payment.refund.completed",
    "data" : {
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

Im using aspJSON1.17.asp to be able to convert the json data with this code.

```
theinfo=request.form("something")
jsonstring = theinfo
        'response.write jsonstring 
        Set oJSON = New aspJSON

        'Load JSON string
        oJSON.loadJSON(jsonstring)
        theevent=oJSON.data("event")
```

So if I then just do this, will that work?

```
if theevent="payment.checkout.completed" then
response.write "Yepp the payment is completed, insert it into the db now!"
end if
```

And also, how can I test if the webhook is being send to the `getorderinfo.asp page`?

As you can see, I´m totally new, so any input really appreciated, thanks.

Just to see if I getting anything sent to my getorderinfo.asp page I have this.

```
theinfo = CStr(Request.Form)
if theinfo<>"" then 
testing=123
    sql= "INSERT INTO ordrar(userId) VALUES ("&testing&");"
    conn.Execute (sql)
end if
```

But this is not inserting anything in my db?

Comment: Nothing special to do here. I'm not good at asp, but your webhook page looks exactly same like that of a registration page or login page. You expect a post request, you read the form body content and process it. The only difference in webhook is that, instead of from one of your own webpage, request originate from a server. No difference in handling the post request at your side.

Comment: Thanks Mat, but their docs says that they are sending  the json data, how do I receive the hole json data so I can convert it with my "New aspJson" code? What should the request.form be?

Comment: Mat, just one more question? When I declare the web hook url, can I then add a variable to it like this  """url"": ""https://mydomain.se/getorderinfo.asp?myvariable=somevalue"",", I mean is that a standard way you can add your own data, or is that up to the payment service and how the allow the url to look like, I hope you understand. Thanks a lot for you simple answer before. It was so simple as I thought, but I was´t sure, so you clarified it well!

Comment: yes you can add anything to url, I'm not sure how to parse json data in asp, but request.body or similar if such a property exists, will be the json string they sent

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the link and json above, how would a url look like that I would get with the json data?

Comment: You can use [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or [insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) to send a post request with the json data to that url of yours for debugging purposes. Then you can see for yourself what you are getting and how to handle it. When the server send a webhook request, it will look same way to your asp page.

Comment: Mat, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Claes, did you get this working?  I'd be curious to see how your ultimate code compared to what you have above below "Just to see if I getting anything sent to my getorderinfo.asp page I have this."

Answer (score 2):

all JSON is transmitted as Binary data, so instead of request.form or request.querystring
you request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes) <-- then convert to ASCII 
see code sample below

hope that helps

```
<%
If Request.TotalBytes=0 then 
response.write("Form Data:" & request.form &"<br>---<br>")
response.write("QueryString Data:" & request.querystring&"<br>---<br>")
else 
response.write("Binary Data Converted to string for WEbhooks or receive JSON data<br>---- <br>" )
response.write(Request.TotalBytes & "-Total Bytes ")

    Dim lngBytesCount, post
    lngBytesCount = Request.TotalBytes
    post = BytesToStr(Request.BinaryRead(lngBytesCount))
    Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
    Response.Write "Your " & Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") & " data was: " & post
End If

Function BytesToStr(bytes)
    Dim Stream
    Set Stream = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
        Stream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary
        Stream.Open
        Stream.Write bytes
        Stream.Position = 0
        Stream.Type = 2 'adTypeText
        Stream.Charset = "iso-8859-1"
        BytesToStr = Stream.ReadText
        Stream.Close
    Set Stream = Nothing
End Function
%>
```

Comment: Brilliant.  That worked like a charm for a webhook from shopify.  Thanks jb